# Chinese characters in UTF8?

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8, chinese-locale

I have some characters that I believe was originally chinese but are now transformed to some type of encoding, of which I don't know what.

The characters are

```
ÑÅÇª
```

Is there any way to change these back into there chinese counterparts?

Comment: may be you can change  to gbk from utf-8

Comment: I tried that.. it just stays the same...

Comment: what do you do ?

Comment: Entered the file into a text editor and saved as gbk and gb2312.. saved and opened...and also tried online converter.. same thing

Comment: I'm guessing some brain-dead old program has probbaly changed the file to iso 8859-1 or something. See my more detailed answer below.

Comment: Is this how they should look? 脩脜脟陋  If so what you copied into the question is still in Chinese Simplified encoding. You may just be able to convert that to UTF-8 and make sure the database tables are also set to UTF-8 for the future (utf8_general_ci, I believe, in mysql)... All I did was change my view of this page, to 'simplified' copy, change back to unicode, paste.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt mention where/how these are stored. (web page, database, text file etc). It really depends on whether the charachters are still in their native encoding or if something has tried to re-encode them along the way. It may be as simple as to change the encoding used to view the text (such as in the menu of most browsers, and decent text editors) back to the original encoding (eg: Chinese, Simplified, Traditional, or Big5 etc (Sorry Im not up on the proper Chinese encodings, my experience has been with Japanese).

You may be able to use utilities such as iconv to re-encode the file into UTF-8, provided you know the original encoding (or find a utility that can auto-detect).

If the file has been transformed along the way you will probably have to try and reverse that, so that it it returns to the original encoding before trying to recover it, hoewever sometimes an incorrect encoding cant be reversed. (information loss).

Going forward, UTF-8 is probably the encoding you'll want to migrate the text to, if you can recover it.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233978/recovering-utf-8-from-broken-iso-latin-1-sequence) may also be helpful

Comment: They was stored in a MYSQL database, so whoever registered on the website.. it got put into the MYSQL database and thats it.

Comment: @x34c4 Check the encoding on the table. You'll probably find that its latin-1. youl'll have to try convert back from that, but Im not sure that's possible.